# Unable to connect cqlsh after alter system_auth keyspace with wrong DC name

Tags: cassandra-3.0

We have altered the system_auth keyspace with DC names like 'Asia' and 'DC2'. But Asia DC name not exist. instead of 'DC1' (Data center name) we altered with 'Asia'. After that we can't perform any alter in that session and not able to connect cqlsh after came out from the session. getting below error.

alter KEYSPACE system_auth WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'Asia': '3', 'DC2': '3'} AND durable_writes = true;

Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': AuthenticationFailed('Failed to authenticate to 127.0.0.1: Error from server: code=0100 [Bad credentials] message="Unable to perform authentication: Cannot achieve consistency level QUORUM"',)})

Question: 1)How to fix this issue?
2) why alter command not complain if DC is not exist?
3) is there any way to bypass these kind of issues?

looking for fix/solution